# How to get information from DataList's footer on buttonClick

Tags: c#, asp.net, datalist, findcontrol

I have an ASP.NET `DataList`, with a footer defined thus:

```
<FooterTemplate>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStatusList" runat="server">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <input id="txtNotes" type="text" placeholder="Notes" />
    <asp:Button runat="server" type="button" Text="Add" ID="btnAdd"></asp:Button>
</FooterTemplate>
```

What I'm looking to do, is, on click of `btnAdd`, get the values from `txtNotes` and `ddlStatusList`, but I can't work out how to access the controls, let alone the values.

I can't follow something like [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/175355/Get-the-values-from-Datalist) because I won't be able to check if my button has been clicked (as is possible with a checkbox), and even then, I'm not sure if I'll be able to use `findControl` as demonstrated. (Does a `DataList`'s footer behave differently to an item?)

I can't use the `Button`'s `commandName` & `commandValue` attributes because, when databound, the text inputted won't exist and therefore I can't set the `CommandValue`.

I have tried using a `LinkButton` rather than a normal .NET `Button`, but come accross the same issue, whereby I cannot work out how to get the values from the `TextBox`/`DropDownList`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following should work. See I added runat="Server" for txtNotes:

aspx:

```
<FooterTemplate>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStatusList" runat="server">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <input id="txtNotes" runat="server" type="text" placeholder="Notes" />
    <asp:Button runat="server" type="button" Text="Add" ID="btnAdd"></asp:Button>
 </FooterTemplate>
```

C#:

```
protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var txtNotes = (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputText)(((Button)sender).Parent).FindControl("txtNotes");
        var ddlStatusList = (DropDownList)(((Button)sender).Parent).FindControl("ddlStatusList");
    }
```

Comment: +1 - Excellent!!! DataList's DataListItems are null at postback. This is one of the best approaches, I think.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Control.NamingContainer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txxbk90b%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to access other controls in a row:

```
    <FooterTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStatusList" runat="server">
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <input id="txtNotes" type="text" placeholder="Notes" runat="server" />
        <asp:Button runat="server" type="button" Text="Add" ID="btnAdd" OnClick="btnAdd_Click"></asp:Button>
    </FooterTemplate>

    protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button btnAdd = (Button)sender;
        DropDownList ddlStatusList = (DropDownList)btnAdd.NamingContainer.FindControl("ddlStatusList");
        System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputText txtNotes = (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputText)btnAdd.NamingContainer.FindControl("txtNotes");
        int index = ddlStatusList.SelectedIndex;
        string text = txtNotes.Value;
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the naming container (DataListItem) is null at postback. This will work for a GridView, but not for a DataList.